# Fail To deploy Mule app in Mule standalone Runtime

Tags: mule

I got the below error, while deploy my mule app in Mule server, it seems like error occurring on DataMapper, but the same app is running fine with mule studio.I getting this error only when i use data mapper in application, what could the cause for the error plz aasit

> org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex
>   -type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'data-mapper:config
>   '. One of '`

Comment: DataMapper is an Enterprise Edition only feature, do you have an EE license? If so you should contact MuleSoft Support directly.

Comment: @genjosanzo, can i get example on, servlet endpoint mule application, i couldn't get an idea on how to pass value to that servlet in Mule runtime server from Swing, even this query is not related to above question, plz assist.

Answer (score 0):

@genjosanzo, thanks for a hint, i was using Community version, now mule application is working fine in Enterprise version - question CLOSED